# How to pass exitCode from program to Docker container?

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I am running a Go binary program in a Docker container. The program returns an exit code using the following line of code:

```
os.Exit(exitCode)
```

The Dockerfile contains this line to run the program:

```
CMD ./bin/program [param1] [param2]
```

I want to pass the exit code up to the Docker container. Currently, when I use the following command to check the pod's status after execution I always get 0 no matter what exitCode the program returned.

```
kubectl get pod [podname] --output=yaml

(below is a snippet from the output returned)
state:
  terminated:
    containerID: [some id]
    exitCode: 0
    finishedAt: [timestamp]
    reason: Completed
    startedAt: [timestamp]
```

The reason I want to do this is because if the program failed, I want the deployment itself to fail and alert me. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does your pod spec declare a `command:` or `args:`?  Is there anything else in `CMD`, or does your image have an `ENTRYPOINT`?  In general, a container runs one process, and the exit status of that process is the exit status of the container.

Comment: No, the spec doesn't declare a `command:` or `args:` . The Dockerfile contains some other set up steps (RUN, COPY, etc.) before finally CMD. The CMD is just the one command to run the program. There is no ENTRYPOINT. I'm not sure if I have set this up correctly though. Even if I change the CMD to `CMD echo 1` , the exit code is still 0 when I check the pod afterwards.